# Crear archivo temporal y abrirlo con pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, archivo, pandas

Estoy tratando de crear un excel temporal y abrirlo, para más tarde eliminarlo. Con ello lo que pretendo realizar es que se pueda consultar un excel sin tener que guardar nada en memoria.

Mi código es:

```
  def abrir(self):
    nombreFichero = "Temporal"+datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()+".xlsx"
    handle, fn = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.xlsx')
    self.writer = pd.ExcelWriter(nombreFichero, engine='openpyxl')
    self.df.toexcel(self.writer)
```

Pero no me llega a crear en ningún momento el archivo temporal...

Comment: No deberías hacer algún tipo de `self.writer.save()`?

Answer (score 0):

El archivo si que es creado, pero lo hace en **el directorio por defecto para archivos temporales, lo cual depende del sistema operativo**, por ejemplo `/tmp` en GNU/Linux..

Si quieres que se cree en un directorio determinado debes usar el argumento `dir` para indicar la ruta. En general es preferible usar el directorio por defecto, esto facilita la limpieza futura, incluso el sistema operativo  suele estar configurado (aunque esto ya depende del sistema concreto) para limpiar los archivos temporales automáticamente al reinicio, cierre de sesión, por tiempo, etc. Si colocas el archivo en otro directorio impides que el sistema elimine el archivo si por algo no pudo ser eliminado por el proceso. Hay que tener en cuenta que una archivo temporal puede no ser eliminado por el programa que lo creó, bien porque no lo elimine explícitamente o, lo que es más común, porque se produzca una terminación no controlada del proceso que lo creó antes de que este pudiera eliminarlo.

Por otro lado, `tempfile.mkstemp` retorna una tupla en la que el primer elemento es el descriptor de archivo y el segundo la ruta al mismo, usa este retorno para acceder al archivo.

```
import os
import tempfile
import pandas as pd

def abrir():
    prefix = f"Temporal{datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}"
    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=prefix, suffix='.xlsx', dir=os.getcwd())
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
    self.df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

Para guardar los cambios en el archivo debes llamar al método  `save` de `self.writer` o mejor usar `with` para que se encarge automáticamente de guardar y cerrar al terminar. Ten en cuenta que a diferencia de `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` o `tempfile.TemporaryFile` eres responsable de eliminar el archivo manualmente cuando termines, por lo que no olvides llamar a `os.remove(path)` cuando termines con el. El cómo ya depende de tu caso concreto, generalmente se recurre a un `try - finally` para asegurarse de que el archivo es destruido a pesar de posibles excepciones:

```
def abrir(self):
    prefix = f"Temporal{datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}" 
    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix=prefix, suffix='.xlsx', dir=os.getcwd())
    try:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            self.df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')

        # Resto de tareas con el archivo

    finally:
        os.remove(path)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Pero si hago el 'os.remove(path)' me da error porque me indica que el excel está siendo utilizado en otro proceso. A mayores, aunque esté la opción 'openpyxl' indicada no me llega a abrir el excel, ¿sabes cuál es el problema?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "no  me llega a abrir el Excel"? ¿No te genera el archivo con el contenido de DataFrame?  Si lo que esperas es que te abra Excel.exe esto no va a suceder, openpyxl es una biblioteca que permite leer y escribir archivos xlsx y que en este caso le indicas a Pandas que use esta biblioteca cómo motor para tal fin.

Comment: Si quieres abrir Excel.exe tienes que dentro del try lanzar el proceso vía subprocess o similar, esperar a que termine (se cierre excel) y entonces eliminar el archivo . Compartir un archivo temporal entre procesos no es nada sencillo, sobretodo en Windows y cuando uno de los procesos es algo completamente externo a Python como es Excel.exe.